# Thymeleaf dynamic list setter

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I would like to simplify some code of mine. It's quite simple honestly. I have 1 input field, and if a certain condition is fulfilled, it should have 1 more attribute. It should have the `list` attribute. The Problem I'm having is, that I don't know how to dynamically set an attribute.

The code looks like this currently:

```
           <input th:if="${fieldIndex == 0 && !#arrays.contains(dropDownFields, y)}"
                   th:disabled="${#arrays.contains(disabledFields, y)}"
                   th:field="*{ZMatrixValues[__${dataIndex}__].tableValues[__${i}__][__${y}__]}"
                   class="table-input" type="text" onfocus="focused(this)">

            <input th:if="${fieldIndex == 0 && #arrays.contains(dropDownFields, y)}"
                   list="list"
                   th:disabled="${#arrays.contains(disabledFields, y)}"
                   th:field="*{ZMatrixValues[__${dataIndex}__].tableValues[__${i}__][__${y}__]}"
                   class="table-input" type="text" onfocus="focused(this)">
```

And as you can see, the 2 input fields are the exact same, except when this condition is true: `#arrays.contains(dropDownFields, y)`, then it should also add the attribute `list="list"`. Is there any easier way than copying so much code?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `th:if` you can use [`th:attr`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute) and place the conditional logic in that attribute using the Thymeleaf "if-then-else" operator: `(if) ? (then) : (else)`.

Here is a simplified version of your code showing this:

```
<input th:attr="list=${#arrays.contains(dropDownFields, y) ? 'some_value' : null}">
```

If the `#arrays.contains` condition is true, then the `list` attribute will be added to the `<input>` element; otherwise if the condition is false, and the `null` is returned, then no attribute will be added.

Instead of `'some_value'` you can use whatever you want - including the `th:field` expression from your question.

All the other attributes in your question can be included in the tag, and will be unaffected, since they are not part of the `(if) ? (then) : (else)` logic.